# Flutter HexCode

Tags: colors, flutter

When I'm using (Colors.amberAccent) in Flutter framework, the color square appears automatically. How can I show it in Android studio beside Lines number if I'm using Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 100, 23)?

The second question is, can I use this color style (#ff0000) in Flutter framework?

I've put an image to clear my idea.[colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Pyy.jpg)

Comment: see `Colors#fromHexString`

Answer (score 1):

```
String color = '#ff0000';
String hex = color.replaceAll("#", "");
Color col = Color(int.parse(hex, radix: 16)).withOpacity(1.0);
```

P.S. Or, you can use [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/color)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: It is not possible to display the color in the IDE when you use something else that `Colors.colorName`.

For your second question: you can use the style you described with this syntax `Color(0xff5600)`. That will return a `Color` object instance

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: appTitle,
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: : Color(0xff5600),
  ),
  home: ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The color square will appear if you put the color as a constant:

```
Color color = const Color(0xFF536DFE);
```